# Delegate and DataSource classname

Tags: ios, naming-conventions

What would be a good name for class which defines both delegate as well datasource methods?

Something like creating a class for defining tableview datasource as well delegate methods

Comment: If I have a view to display news feed, i would named it `FeedViewControllerProtocols`, or `FeedTableViewProtocols` :)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these coding guidelines for [Objective-C](https://github.com/raywenderlich/objective-c-style-guide) and [Swift](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use the main purpose of the datasource or delegate as prefix as @PNRR suggested in his comment. ie for example `LeagueProtocol` and `LeagueDatasource`.

You can refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html) link for more info about the naming convention of methods used and Delegates